# jQuery child elements with same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Imagine that I have this HTML structure:

```
    <div id="bodyRead">
          ...
            <div id="List"></div>
    </div>

   ...

    <div id="bodyWrite">
          ...
            <div id="List"></div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, I have the `#List` inside two different divs (bodyRead and bodyWrite). For a lighter code, I preferred to work with id instead of class (even knowing that duplicate IDs isn't valid, the code makes more sense to me), and selecting the `#List` on jQuery like this:

```
$('#bodyRead #List').off('click').on('click', function() ...
$('#bodyWrite #List').off('click').on('click', function() ...
```

works. I'm always taking care of make duplicate IDs only on child divs, where I can separate them by their parent div on jQuery selector.

Is this approach very wrong? I mean, this can get me in trouble?

Comment: Use `class` attribute instead `id` to repeat ALWAYS.

Comment: Do not use the same id for more than one element. Use classes instead or a custom attribute.

Comment: Yes, I know this is the obvious answer... But as I said, for a lighter code, I preferred to work with ID, since it makes more sense to me (in terms of code reviewing)...

Comment: @user3810691 - ID is a UNIQUE identifier as per the HTML spec.  it should NOT be repeated in a document.  Even if it "makes more sense' to you -- its incorrect.  see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

don't duplicate your Id even in child element .. change it to **class="List"**
then you can use

```
$('.List').on('click',function(){
    var getparent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    alert(getparent);
});
```

and if **class="List"** not first level child of any of #bodyRead or #bodyWrite

add class to it

```
 <div id="bodyRead" class="mainDiv">
 <div id="bodyWrite" class="mainDiv">
```

and then use

```
$('.List').on('click',function(){
    var getclosest = $(this).closest('.mainDiv').attr('id');
    alert(getclosest);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should expect that CSS and JavaScript (including jQuery and other frameworks) behave in accordance with the HTML specifications.  ID must be unique, multiple instances of the same ID is not supported.  See below:

From HTML 4.01 spec:

> id = name [CS] This attribute assigns a name to an element. **This name**
> **must be unique in a document.**
>
> class = cdata-list [CS] This attribute
> assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number
> of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple
> class names must be separated by white space characters.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

This is from the HTML 5 spec:

> 3.2.5.1 The id attribute
>
> The id attribute specifies its **element's unique identifier** (ID). [DOM]
>
> **The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home**
> **subtree** and must contain at least one character. The value must not
> contain any space characters.
>
> There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in
> particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start
> with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.
>
> An element's unique identifier can be used for a variety of purposes,
> most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a document using
> fragment identifiers, as a way to target an element when scripting,
> and as a way to style a specific element from CSS.
>
> Identifiers are opaque strings. Particular meanings should not be
> derived from the value of the id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Although id selectors are meant to be unique your code will work as long as you make sure to use correct nesting. In other words `#bodyRead #List` and `#bodyWrite #List` are perfectly fine as long as you don't create ambiguity by leaving out the parent selectors to `#List`.

Still, using multiple identical ids on the same page is just asking for trouble. You should reconsider switching to class selectors or reevaluate if it is really worth the potential trouble of sticking with your original idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well i feel this is a bad approach because the browser creates the DOM(document object model) for the page, which takes into consideration that each Id has a unique value.It would be hard to play with the duplicate Id's in javascript when you want to manipulate you need to consider parent as well as child id each time. So its better to use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly should not use duplicate id's in an html page. If you have a similar concept within two different div's then class makes more sense anyway. So change the `List` ids to classes and then you can access them like this:

```
$('#bodyRead .List').off('click').on('click', function() ...
$('#bodyWrite .List').off('click').on('click', function() ...
```

Even if your code works now due to how jQuery works, because the html specifications say not to do this, you can not know for certain that your code will continue to work in the future.